# PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra

I am trying to use multiprocessing in python to execute Cassandra queries. I have made a queue using

```
futures = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=5)
```

and I am trying to pass this queue to the target function as

```
Process(target=worker, args=(monthyear, daymonthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, process_n, futures)).start()
```

My target function is

```
def worker(monthyear, daymonthyear, ts1, country, lat, lon, sma, dma, etype, version, ihl, tos_dscp, totallen, idnum, fragoff, ttl, proto, hdrchksm, sip, dip, opts, t_sp, t_dp, t_sqnum, t_acknum, t_dataoff, t_flags, t_winsz, t_chksm, t_urgptr, t_opts, p, futures):

    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
    metadata = cluster.metadata
    session = cluster.connect()

    session.execute("USE test;")
    print current_process().name

    future = session.execute_async("INSERT INTO test.day (daymonthyear, ts, c_country, c_lat, c_lon, e_sma, e_dma, e_etype, ip_version, ip_ihl, ip_tos_dscp, ip_totallen, ip_idnum, ip_fragoff, ip_ttl, ip_proto, ip_hdrchksm, ip_sip, ip_dip, ip_opts, s_sp, s_dp, s_vtag, s_chksm) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(str(daymonthyear), int(ts1), str(country), str(lat), str(lon), str(sma), str(dma), str(etype), str(version), str(ihl), str(tos_dscp), int(totallen), int(idnum), str(fragoff), int(ttl), int(proto), str(hdrchksm), str(sip), str(dip), str(opts), int(s_sp), int(s_dp), int(s_vtag), str(s_chksm)))

    futures.put_nowait(future)

    future = session.execute_async("INSERT INTO test.month (monthyear, ts, c_country, c_lat, c_lon, e_sma, e_dma, e_etype, ip_version, ip_ihl, ip_tos_dscp, ip_totallen, ip_idnum, ip_fragoff, ip_ttl, ip_proto, ip_hdrchksm, ip_sip, ip_dip, ip_opts, u_sp, u_dp, u_len, u_chksm) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(str(monthyear), int(ts1), str(country), str(lat), str(lon), str(sma), str(dma), str(etype), str(version), str(ihl), str(tos_dscp), int(totallen), int(idnum), str(fragoff), int(ttl), int(proto), str(hdrchksm), str(sip), str(dip), str(opts), int(u_sp), int(u_dp), int(u_len), str(u_chksm)))

    futures.put_nowait(future)

    session.cluster.shutdown()
    session.shutdown()
```

Then I am checking for a certain number of future objects in the queue and the removing the objects from the queue using futures.get_nowait() but I am getting a pickling error. The queue should be pickable but I am not getting why this error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

The cassandra-driver objects are not pickle-able. i.e `cluster` and `session`

I would recommend creating the driver objects outside of the `worker` function's scope to avoid pickling them. It is overkill to have a session and cluster per query anyway.

```
# Initialise global cluster connection.
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
metadata = cluster.metadata
session = cluster.connect()

futures = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=5)

Process( target=worker, args=(args) ).start()

session.cluster.shutdown()
session.shutdown()

# Workers now share global connection.
def worker(*args):

    session.execute("USE test;")
    print current_process().name

    future = session.execute_async("INSERT INTO ...")

    futures.put_nowait(future)

    future = session.execute_async("INSERT INTO ...")

    futures.put_nowait(future)`
```